# In listview not displaying some languages but for the same code in other device it is showing

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

ChooseLanguage.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.R;
import picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.SplashScreen;
import picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.Volley.RegisterUser;

public class ChooseLanguage extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ListView choose_lang;
    String[] languagelist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        languagelist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Langusges);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_language);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.language_list,languagelist);
        choose_lang = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.languages);
        choose_lang.setAdapter(adapter);

        choose_lang.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SplashScreen.Language = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),SplashScreen.Language,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                RegisterUser registerUser = new RegisterUser();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

strings.xml

```
<array name="Langusges">
        <item>हिंदी</item>
        <item>తెలుగు</item>
        <item>தமிழ்</item>
        <item>മലയാളം</item>
        <item>ಕನ್ನಡ</item>
        <item>English</item>
        <item>मराठी</item>
        <item>বাংলা</item>
        <item>ગુજરાતી</item>
        <item>ਪੰਜਾਬੀ</item>
        <item>ଓଡିଆ</item>
        <item>भोजपुरी</item>
        <item>नेपाली</item>
        <item>हरयनवी</item>
        <item>कश्मीरी</item>
        <item>অসমীয়া</item>
        <item>कोंकणी</item>
    </array>
```

The result as I'm getting:

[image]

All languages are displaying but as shown in this image 3 languages are not displaying and even when I click on that item blank will be toasted and when I click on other languages then shows the clicked languages.In my tab it is not showing 3 languages and in other sony phone it is showing other languages only one languages is showing but that is in another format.

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tab does not support these languages. But the other devices in which you are testing does.

Comment: ok, but is there any way to make it support. if possible. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't have knowledge about it. I think we can not but if i look into a computer, we do add fonts in MS Word, so maybe it's possible but i'm not sure about it.